# html/css borders in rows only

Tags: html, css, rows

I've been working on this code for a bit now and have run into a wall. I'm sure it's just because I've been staring at it long enough that in my mind I feel like I've tried every solution, but I can't seem to get a border to run just along the top and bottom of each row in this table.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title></title>
 <style>

 #data_table {
    td {    
            border-bottom: solid;
            background-color: #000099;
            font-family: arial;
            font-size: 12px;
    }
    th {
            background-color: #cccccc;
            font-family: arial;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-weight: bold;


 }
  border-top-width: 1px;
border-top-style: solid; /* double, dashed, dotted... */
border-top-color: #000;

    border-bottom-width: 3px;
border-bottom-style: solid; /* double, dashed, dotted... */
border-bottom-color: #000;





    margin: 8px;
padding: 0px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;

word-wrap: break-word;
table-layout: fixed;
width: 700px;
background-color: #f5f5f5


 }
 </style>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="testreport.php" method="post">
 First Name: <input type="text" name="FirstName">
 Last Name: <input type="text" name="LastName">
 Start Date(YYYY-MM-DD): <input type="text" name="StartDate">
 End Date(YYYY-MM-DD): <input type="text" name="EndDate">
 <input type="submit">
 </form>

     <table id="data_table"><tr><th align=left>Date</th><th align=left>Description</th><th align=left>Amount</th></th><th align=left>Balance</th><tr><td>2009-08-01</td><td>YDP 09/10: Registration Fee for Lauren Stone</td><td>25.00</td><td>Balance</td></tr><tr><td>2009-08-01</td><td>YDP 09/10: Tuition for Lauren Stone (Quarter 1)</td><td>1275.75</td><td>Balance</td></tr><tr><td>2009-10-01</td><td>YDP 09/10: Tuition for Lauren Stone (Quarter 2)</td><td>1275.75</td><td>Balance</td></tr><tr><td>2009-12-01</td><td>YDP 09/10: Tuition for Lauren Stone (Quarter 3)</td><td>1275.75</td><td>Balance</td></tr><tr><td>2010-02-01</td><td>YDP 09/10: Tuition for Lauren Stone (Quarter 4)</td><td>1275.75</td><td>Balance</td></tr><tr><td>2010-08-01</td><td>YDP 10/11: Registration Fee for Lauren Stone</td><td>25.00</td><td>Balance</td></tr><tr><td>2010-08-01</td><td>YDP 10/11: Tuition for Lauren Stone (Quarter 1)</td><td>1084.81</td><td>Balance</td></tr><tr><td>2010-10-01</td><td>YDP 10/11: Tuition for Lauren Stone (Quarter 2)</td><td>1084.81</td><td>Balance</td></tr><tr><td>2010-12-01</td><td>YDP 10/11: Tuition for Lauren Stone (Quarter 3)</td><td>1084.80</td><td>Balance</td></tr><tr><td>2011-02-01</td><td>YDP 10/11: Tuition for Lauren Stone (Quarter 4)</td><td>1084.81</td><td>Balance</td></tr></table>        

</body>
```

Comment: Which element you are applying the code starting with this line `border-top-width: 1px;`? I suppose it should be `tr`

Comment: Horribly malformed CSS.

Comment: @ Scott: I agree, I'm not an HTML/CSS coder. Thanks for the constructive input though, Scott. That practically solved all the issues, clearly what this site was meant for.

Comment: @Morpheus I tried adding that section to tr but it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed some thing. As this code of CSS is not so good. Modify by me use it.

```
<style>

 #data_table {
    border-top-width: 1px;
border-top-style: solid; /* double, dashed, dotted... */
border-top-color: #000;

    border-bottom-width: 3px;
border-bottom-style: solid; /* double, dashed, dotted... */
border-bottom-color: #000;
 margin: 8px;
padding: 0px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;

word-wrap: break-word;
table-layout: fixed;
width: 700px;
background-color: #f5f5f5


 }

#data_table td {    
            border-bottom: solid;
            background-color: #000099;
            font-family: arial;
            font-size: 12px;
    }
   #data_table th {
            background-color: #cccccc;
            font-family: arial;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-weight: bold;


 }
 </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `#data_table td {}` and `#data_table th{}` separately instead of nested format you have currently.

check out here:
http://jsfiddle.net/aCjMn/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/dolours/s25jN/ This fiddle will solve the issue

```
#data_table {
   border-top-width: 1px;
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-color: #000;
border-bottom-width: 3px;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-color: #000;
margin: 8px;
padding: 0px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
word-wrap: break-word;
table-layout: fixed;
width: 700px;
background-color: #f5f5f5;
border-spacing: 0px;

 }

#data_table td {    
            border-bottom: solid;

            font-family: arial;
            font-size: 12px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
    }
   #data_table th {
            background-color: #cccccc;
            font-family: arial;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-weight: bold;


 }
```